# Batch code to show all pc's in a domain

Tags: batch-file

I tried to look some things up, but I'm unable to find what i look for.

I would like to have a code that can do this:

- Scan the domain for all pc's that are connected to the domain (online and offline (if possible).
- Then i would like to write all those names to a file (I think i can do that)
- Afterwards it should have a code in another file to execute a few commands (which i already have written) for every pc in the file.

So it would kinda look like this:

GetSysteminfo.bat

```
Scan domain for every pc >> PcNames.txt
For %%EveryPC IN (PcNames.txt) Do (
Commands (i will post them if neccesary)
)
```

The output file would look like:
PcInfo.txt

```
PC01
information

PC02
information

PC03
information

etc.
```

I hope you understand what i try to get.
Thanks in advance for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the tools `netdom` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217.aspx) and the domain administration credentials.

then you might

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('netdom query WORKSTATION') do (
    echo %%a >>results.txt
    yourcommand %%a >>results.txt
    echo. >>results.txt
 )
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with purely code.
I mean withouth using external tools etc.?

Comment: @P.A. Is it possible to do it with purely code? I mean withouth using external tools etc.?

Comment: you need some tool to inspect the domain, `netdom` is the most obvious.